# It's important to learn / learning a language when you're young

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

It's important **to learn** / **learning** a language when you're young.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! What are your thoughts about the sentence? Which option would you choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most naturally-looking option is to use the "to-infinitive":

> It's important to learn a language when you're young.

If you want to use "learning", you might remodel the sentence:

> Learning a language when you're young is important.

Furthermore, "to learn" can also be put in the subject position:

> To learn a language when you're young is important.

---

Some linguists call the pronoun "it" in sentences like yours a "[syntactic expletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive)".

Here's a nice [foray into the history of dummy pronouns and syntactic expletives](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/287762/48335).

Comment: When you have the following type of structure:  It  +  be + an adjective + to infinitive,  is the one that follows the adjective.